# R: a function to search for values spread across multiple columns, where the columns are grouped

Tags: r, grouped-table

I have a tibble similar to this, but with many more columns:

| Bead_003_normalized | Bead_003_serology | Bead_003_CI | Bead_003_result | Bead_004_normalized | Bead_004_serology | Bead_004_CI | Bead_004_result | A2_result | A*02:01_result | A*02:03_result |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 5000 | A2 | A*02:01 | NA | 7000 | A2 | A*02:03 | NA | TRUE | FALSE | FALSE |
| 1200 | A2 | A*02:03 | NA | 500 | A2 | A*02:06 | NA | FALSE | FALSE | TRUE |
| 9000 | A2 | A*02:01 | NA | 500 | A2 | A*02:06 | NA | FALSE | TRUE | FLASE |

The set of columns on the left are information about individual beads in a lab test, with 4 columns of values per bead. The last three columns on the right are results of manual analysis of the test.

I want to write a function that will assign positive/negative to the "Bead_XXX_result" columns based on the value in the "AXX_result" columns. My intended result for this example would be this:

| Bead_003_normalized | Bead_003_serology | Bead_003_CI | Bead_003_result | Bead_004_normalized | Bead_004_serology | Bead_004_CI | Bead_004_result | A2_result | A*02:01_result | A*02:03_result |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 5000 | A2 | A*02:01 | positive | 7000 | A2 | A*02:03 | positive | TRUE | FALSE | FALSE |
| 1200 | A2 | A*02:03 | positive | 500 | A2 | A*02:06 | NA | FALSE | FALSE | TRUE |
| 9000 | A2 | A*02:01 | positive | 500 | A2 | A*02:06 | NA | FALSE | TRUE | FLASE |

Essentially, whenever there is a TRUE value in one of the AXX_result columns, I want the function to search for the character string of the column name in any of multiple columns grouped by bead (I could certainly remove the "_result" from the names of last three columns if that would make it easier). It seems creating a nested table, with groups based on bead, is the way to go, and then maybe using something from the purrr package, but I'm not sure how to set it up.

Comment: Is this related to the column names in `Bead_003_CI`

Comment: e.g. the column shows `A*02:06`, but those column names are not present

Comment: The beads can have different properties, which is why I can't just hard-code a function to look at specific columns. In the first row, bead 003 has a low-resolution value of A2, and a high-resolution value of A*02:01. The `A2_result` column has a value of TRUE, so bead 003 and 004 should both be positive, since the value of `Bead_003_serology` and `Bead_004_serology` are both "A2."

Comment: In the final dataset, all columns will be present, but that will be hundreds of columns wide, so I was just using an example. It shouldn't change the logic (I think)!